# BeautifulSoup code not porting to Windows 8 device for strange reasons

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have written code to scrape Wikipedia for links using BeautifulSoup, requests, and lxml parser as imports that aren't built into Python 2.7.
I created a batch file that will run get-pip.py and then install everything the person who launched the bat file will need to run my program. I got this to work on Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Windows 10 and Fedora but when I run on a Windows 8 machine, I get the most absurd errors.

I specify, in my code, that when I initialize a BeautifulSoup object that it uses 'lxml' parser. So here is the sample code from Python.

`soupobj = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'lxml')`

The code won't run(on windows 8) unless I change the above to

`soupobj = BeautifulSoup(source_code)`

Also, I can't have the following:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString`

It must be

`from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString`

Otherwise it will say it couldn't create a BeautifulSoup object.

The weirdest error of all comes from when I change all the above to get it to finally start to run. It will run fine for a few links and then it will say

`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'name'`

when I do the following:

`for element in contents_section.contents:`
`if element.name == 'ul':`

But on every other machine, it never once threw this error during debugging and I can't replicate this error on the windows 8 machine.

I desperately need to get this code to work on Windows 8 because the user is not in the slightest decent at technical issues, and this needs to be deploy-able but it has so many issues on windows 8. On every other machine this code is ready to be deployed and released but windows 8 just falls apart.

Thanks in advance for any help with this very obscure issue.

Comment: Make your `python` versions and `bs4` versions are the same

Comment: They are the exact same on all machines.

Comment: maybe try installing and running the batch script in a [virtual environment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), so you'll have a clean environment and hopefully can narrow down what the possible problem is.

Comment: Everything I ran it on was completely brand new and never touched before. As well as 3 tests on virtual machines of the same exact 'untouched' machines just to be double sure and it still won't work on windows 8

Comment: Your imports suggest that you have installed bs3. You can get the version with `import BeautifulSoup; print(BeautifulSoup.__version__)`

Comment: Install using `pip install beautifulsoup4`, see [Installing Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)